# FluentBit: add dynamic es index

Tags: fluent-bit

I have a working `fluent-bit:1.7`
I need OUTPUT to Elasticsearch and create a dynamic index based on the k8s label = `name`.
I want the following convention for the index:

`infra-${app_name}-yyyy.mm.dd`

Example: `infra-mongodb-2021.01.01`, `infra-postgresql-2021.01.01`, `infra-kafka-2021.01.01` etc...

This is my FILTER and OUTPUT config:

```
[FILTER]
    Name             kubernetes
    Match            kube.*
    Merge_Log        Off
    Keep_Log         Off

[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match kube.*
    Host ${ES_HOST}
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix_Key kubernetes['labels']['name']
```

But it generates the following index: `mongodb-2021.01.01`

It's almost done, I just need to **always** add the `infra-` prefix.

Just to be clear, I need something like:

```
    Logstash_Prefix_Key infra-${kubernetes['labels']['name']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this using Lua plugin to create a field in the record with the name  of the index then using this field as Logstash_Prefix_Key

Lua script (based on https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/scripts/append_tag.lua):

```
function append_es_index(tag, timestamp, record)
    new_record = record

    if (record["cluster_name"] ~= nil) then
        es_index = record["cluster_name"]
    else
        es_index = "k8s"
    end

    if (record["kubernetes"] ~= nil) then
        kube = record["kubernetes"]
        if (kube["namespace_name"] ~= nil and string.len(kube["namespace_name"]) > 0) then
            es_index = es_index .. "." .. kube["namespace_name"]
        end
        
        if (kube["labels"] ~= nil) then
            labels = kube["labels"]

            if (labels["app"] ~= nil and string.len(labels["app"]) > 0) then
                es_index = es_index .. "." .. labels["app"]
            elseif (labels["k8s-app"] ~= nil and string.len(labels["k8s-app"]) > 0) then 
                es_index = es_index .. "." .. labels["k8s-app"]
            elseif (labels["name"] ~= nil and string.len(labels["name"]) > 0) then 
                es_index = es_index .. "." .. labels["name"]
            end
        end
    end

    new_record["es_index"] =  es_index

    return 1, timestamp, new_record
end
```

Fluentbit filters config:

```
[FILTER]
    Name                kubernetes
    ...
[FILTER]
    Name record_modifier
    Match *
    Record cluster_name my-test-cluster
[FILTER]
    Name    lua
    Match   *
    script  /fluent-bit/scripts/append_es_index.lua
    call    append_es_index
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve similar result is to create a label or an annotation for your Pods

for example

```
[OUTPUT]
  Name                es
  Logstash_Prefix_Key kubernetes['labels']['log-key']
...
```

deployment yml based on [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        log-key: infra-nginx # log-key label will be used in Logstash_Prefix_Key
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

this way you will be able to combine multiple "dynamic" data for example also the namespace

Comment: I quiet like this idea @knetsi - using labels as a grouping for pod logs within your log database... great idea!